# Samba setup problem

Tags: samba

After multiple unsuccessful attempts to configure samba shares and installing/uninstalling several times, Samba and system-config-samba will not install correctly. Please see output from installation attempt in terminal. Help appreciated.

```
> Setting up samba (2:4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu3.1) ...
Failed to preset unit: Unit file /etc/systemd/system/samba-ad-dc.service is masked.
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: systemctl preset failed on samba-ad-dc.service: No such file or directory
Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status smbd.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript smbd, action "start" failed.
● smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-02-11 11:34:46 EST; 3ms ago
     Docs: man:smbd(8)
           man:samba(7)
           man:smb.conf(5)
  Process: 26745 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smbd $SMBDOPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 26745 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 11 11:34:46 Mycenae systemd[1]: Starting Samba SMB Daemon...
Feb 11 11:34:46 Mycenae systemd[1]: smbd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 11 11:34:46 Mycenae systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.
Feb 11 11:34:46 Mycenae systemd[1]: smbd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 11 11:34:46 Mycenae systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of system-config-samba:
 system-config-samba depends on samba; however:
  Package samba is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package system-config-samba (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.26-0ubuntu2.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba
 system-config-samba
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: This is when you go to install Samba via the CLI?

Comment: I try to install through Terminal.

Comment: Perhaps I am not asking the question in a way that invites an answer. Is it better to ask: how can the problem that generates this error be fixed. 
> Setting up samba (2:4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu3.1) ...
Failed to preset unit: Unit file /etc/systemd/system/samba-ad-dc.service is masked.
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: systemctl preset failed on samba-ad-dc.service: No such file or directory

Comment: I think I may have resolved the matter by purging samba-common and reinstalling samba. I thought it would be removed when I uninstalled samba.

Comment: No uninstalling can still leave config files, purging removes config files as well

Comment: It turns out that samba-common is not deleted by purging and has to be removed separately.